# flutter Table.fromTextArray iterating a list while creating PDF

Tags: list, loops, flutter, dart

Hello everyone i was just wondering how should i iterate inside Table.fromTextArray which can be found in this package

https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

The Documentation is just very bad from my point of view and i was unable to locate any information that will help me achieve my goal

here is the code

```
   Container(
     margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22, 5, 22, 5),
     child: Directionality(
       textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
       child: Table.fromTextArray(
           headers: <dynamic>['الإجمالي', 'العدد' ,'الخدمة', 'القطعة'],
           cellAlignment: Alignment.center,
           data: <List>[
             [
               '${purchases[0]['total_price']}',
               '${purchases[0]['quantity']}' ,
               '${purchases[0]['service_name_ar']}',
               '${purchases[0]['article_name_ar']}',
             ]
           ]
       ),
     ),
   )
```

as you can see i am printing the first item in the list using the [0] method i want to do it as a foreach how should i do that ?

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE Working Code:

```
  var purchasesAsMap = <Map<String, String>>[
    for(int i = 0; i < purchases.length; i++)
      {
        "total_price": "${purchases[i]['total_price']}",
        "quantity": "${purchases[i]['quantity']}",
        "service_name_ar": "${purchases[i]['service_name_ar']}",
        "article_name_ar": "${purchases[i]['article_name_ar']}",
      },
  ];

  List<List<String>> listOfPurchases=List();
  for(int i=0;i<purchasesAsMap.length;i++)
  {
    listOfPurchases.add(purchasesAsMap[i].values.toList());
  }
```

in build

```
Table.fromTextArray(
                   headers: <dynamic>['الإجمالي', 'العدد' ,'الخدمة', 'القطعة'],
                   cellAlignment: Alignment.center,
                   data: listOfPurchases
               ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
data:<List>[
             [
               for(var value in purchases[0].values) '$value'
             ]
           ]
```

**Edit** :

So after little head scratching I came to this :

```
void main()
{
  
  var listOfMap= <Map<String,String>>[{"name":"abcde","age":"21"},{"name":"xyz","age":"168"},{"name":"iam","age":"12"},{"name":"pqr","age":"1001"}];
  
  List<List<String>> listOfLists=List();
  

  for(int i=0;i<listOfMap.length;i++)
  {

      listOfLists.add(listOfMap[i].values.toList());
  }

 

  
  print(listOfLists.toString());
  
}

// Console :
// [[abcde, 21], [xyz, 168], [iam, 12], [pqr, 1001]]
```

Taking inspiration from above code you can modify your code accordingly , similar to this:

```
List<List<String>> providesListOfLists()
{
 List<List<String>> listOfLists=List();
  

  for(int i=0;i<purchases.length;i++)
  {

      listOfLists.add(purchases[i].values.toList());
  }

return listOfLists;
}
```

And in your `build` method call the function :

```
data:providesListOfLists,
```

Comment: sir what i want exactly is like this 
`for(int i = 0 ; i < purchases.length; i++){
purchases[i]['article_name_ar']
}`

Comment: but the problem is you can't do such a thing inside the data list because `for` is used for functions not widgets , the solution you provided will loop inside the first item only what i want is to loop through the entire purchases list and create 4 widgets for each one of them

Comment: great i think it started to work, however there is a small problem that the collection purchases does contain more data than the four fields mentioned in the question so if we take values it will take the entire collection which will show unnecessary data

Comment: Thanks A lot i found a workaround based on the inspiration you gave i edited the question take a look

Comment: Then the best strategy would be to manually write everything without loops .

Comment: thats not an option because i am fetching data from the api and i don't know exactly how long it is so that i could hard code it

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can easily create pdf here is an example


class PdfSalesApi {
static Future<File> generate(
  tableDataRaw, String totalItems, String totalPrice) async {
final pdf = pw.Document();

final iconImage = (await rootBundle.load('assets/icons/shopping-bag.png'))
    .buffer
    .asUint8List();

final tableHeaders = [
  'Name',
  'Cash',
  'Due',
  'Total',
];

final tableData = tableDataRaw.map((Order e) {
  return [
    e.productInfo,
    e.cash,
    e.due,
    e.totalPrice,
  ];
}).toList();

final List<List<dynamic>> dataTable = [...tableData];

final tableDataFinal = [
  [
    'Coffee',
    '7',
    '\$ 5',
    '1 %',
  ],
  [
    'Blue Berries',
    '5',
    '\$ 10',
    '2 %',
  ],
  [
    'Water',
    '1',
    '\$ 3',
    '1.5 %',
  ],
  [
    'Apple',
    '6',
    '\$ 8',
    '2 %',
  ],
  [
    'Lunch',
    '3',
    '\$ 90',
    '12 %',
  ],
  [
    'Drinks',
    '2',
    '\$ 15',
    '0.5 %',
  ],
  [
    'Lemon',
    '4',
    '\$ 7',
    '0.5 %',
  ],
];

print(tableDataFinal);
print(dataTable);

pdf.addPage(
  pw.MultiPage(
    build: (context) {
      return [
        pw.Row(
          children: [
            pw.Image(
              pw.MemoryImage(iconImage),
              height: 72,
              width: 72,
            ),
            pw.SizedBox(width: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
            pw.Column(
              mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                pw.Text(
                  'Sales Report',
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17.0,
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                      color: PdfColors.green),
                ),
                pw.Text(
                  'ShopExpress',
                  style: const pw.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: PdfColors.grey700,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            pw.Spacer(),
            pw.Column(
              mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                pw.Text(
                  'John Doe',
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.5,
                    fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                pw.Text(
                  'john@gmail.com',
                ),
                pw.Text(
                  Jiffy(DateTime.now()).yMMMMEEEEdjm,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),

        pw.SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
        pw.Divider(),
        pw.SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

        pw.SizedBox(height: 5 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

        ///
        /// PDF Table Create
        ///
        ///
        ///
        ///
        pw.Table.fromTextArray(
          headers: tableHeaders,
          data: dataTable,
          border: null,
          headerStyle: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
          headerDecoration:
              const pw.BoxDecoration(color: PdfColors.grey300),
          cellHeight: 30.0,
          cellAlignments: {
            0: pw.Alignment.centerLeft,
            1: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
            2: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
            3: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
          },
          oddRowDecoration: const pw.BoxDecoration(
            color: PdfColors.grey100,
          ),
        ),
        pw.Divider(),

        pw.Divider(),
        pw.Container(
          alignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
          child: pw.Row(
            children: [
              pw.Spacer(flex: 6),
              pw.Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: pw.Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    pw.Row(
                      children: [
                        pw.Expanded(
                          child: pw.Text(
                            '$totalItems Item(s) Net Total',
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          '\$ $totalPrice',
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    pw.Row(
                      children: [
                        pw.Expanded(
                          child: pw.Text(
                            'Vat 0 %',
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          '\$ 0.0',
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    pw.Divider(),
                    pw.Row(
                      children: [
                        pw.Expanded(
                          child: pw.Text(
                            'Total amount',
                            style: pw.TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          '\$ $totalPrice',
                          style: pw.TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    pw.SizedBox(height: 2 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
                    pw.Container(height: 1, color: PdfColors.grey400),
                    pw.SizedBox(height: 0.5 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
                    pw.Container(height: 1, color: PdfColors.grey400),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        pw.SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
      ];
    },
    footer: (context) {
      var text = 'Page ${context.pageNumber} of ${context.pagesCount}';
      return pw.Column(
        mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          pw.Divider(),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 2 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
          pw.Text(
            'ShopXpress',
            style: pw.TextStyle(
                fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, color: PdfColors.green),
          ),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
          pw.Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              pw.Text(
                'Address: ',
                style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              pw.Text(
                '303/3 Free School St, Dhaka 1205',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
          pw.Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              pw.Text(
                'Email: ',
                style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              pw.Text(
                'shopexpress@gmail.com',
              ),
            ],
          ),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 1 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
          pw.Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              pw.Expanded(
                child: pw.Container(),
              ),
              pw.Text(
                text,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);

return FileHandleApi.saveDocument(name: 'my_sales.pdf', pdf: pdf);
}
}
```

//save and create directory to save pdf and get

```
import 'dart:io';

    import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

    class FileHandleApi {
      static Future<File> saveDocument(
          {required String name, required pw.Document pdf}) async {
        final bytes = await pdf.save();
        final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final file = File('${dir.path}/$name');
        await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
        return file;
      }

      // open pdf file function
      static Future openFile(File file) async {
        final url = file.path;

        await OpenFile.open(url);
      }

       
    }
```